# storing/bringing values from array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to create an array in which I can but some variable adresses and then get to their value from the adress,

here's the code :

```
 SDL_Rect *arraypos[4];

 arraypos[1] = &poskey.x;
 arraypos[2] = &poskey.y;
 arraypos[3] = &posletter.x;
 arraypos[4] = &posletter.y;
```

`posletter` and `poskey` `struct` type :  `SDL_Rect` for more informations :

[enter link description here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Rect)

i made a little test to see if it'll work :

```
printf("%d \n",arraypos[1]);

printf("%d \n",*arraypos[1]); 

printf("%d \n",*arraypos[2]);

printf("%d \n",*arraypos[3]);
```

**if I'm getting it right : '*' next to  'pointer' will give you the value of the variable .**

but all I got  is this warnings :

```
key.c: In function ‘main’:
key.c:49:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 arraypos[1] = &poskey.x;
             ^
 key.c:50:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 arraypos[2] = &poskey.y;
             ^
key.c:51:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 arraypos[3] = &posletter.x;
              ^ 
key.c:52:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 arraypos[4] = &posletter.y;
             ^
key.c:55:12: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%d \n",arraypos[1]);
        ^
```

I tried to ignore them but when I excute the program :

```
rafiq@rafiq-Vostro-3500:~/Desktop/AI$ ./a.out
-1500334368  
0 
0 
0
```

the adress and the rest is zeros.

I don't know what's the appropriate way to create a table of pointers and store adresses on it, and how to bring values from those adresses and apply some modifications on them.

Thank you.

Comment: `arraypos` indexes are `0-3` NOT `1-4`, without seeing the full definition of `struct poskey` it is hard to say what the incompatibility is. Please see: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: i tried it -- nothing changed .

Comment: its an SDL_Rect , check this : https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Rect :) same for posletter

Comment: Please edit your question to give the declaration of `poskey` & `posletter`

Comment: "I tried to ignore them" Is your second fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it difficult to determine exactly what your intent is from the problem statement. Whether you intend to declare an *array of pointers* to type `SDL_Rect` or whether you actually intend to declare and *array of int*. Regarless, the array indexes for an array with (4-elements) are `0-3`, all arrays in C being `zero` *indexed*. e.g.:

```
arraypos[0]
arraypos[1]
arraypos[2]
arraypos[3]
```

**Example with Array of Pointers to type**

Given your edits to your problem statement, you state you want to *"create a table of pointers and store adresses on it"*. If your intent was to declare an array of pointers (`4`) of type `SDL_Rect`, then the following is fine:

```
SDL_Rect *arraypos[4];
```

When you do so, each element of `arraypos` is an *unallocated pointer* to type `SDL_Rect`. There is nothing wrong with that, but you must understand, that is no different from declaring `4` separate pointers to type `SDL_Rect` ( e.g. `SDL_Rect *pointer1;` then `SDL_Rect *pointer2`;, etc...) That will simply declare 4-*unallocated* pointers of type `SDL_Rect`.

That means attempting to store the address of an *integer value alone* as an element of `arraypos` would violate *strict-aliasing* rules even if the size of `SDL_Rect` and `int` are the same. (see: sections 6.5.6 and 6.5.7 of the C standard)

What you can properly store in each element is the address for type `SDL_Rect`. So, if you have `poskey` and `posletter` which are statically declared type `SDL_Rect`, you can make the following assignments:

```
arraypos[0] = &poskey;
arraypos[1] = &posletter;
```

Each arraypos elements now holds a pointer to (e.g. the *address* of a) type `SDL_Rect`. You can then access the `x, y, w, h` values at each address by:

```
arraypos[0]->x;
arraypos[0]->y;
arraypos[1]->x;
arraypos[1]->y;
...
```

A short example using a generic structure of this situation would be:

include

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} SDL_Rect;

int main (void) {

    SDL_Rect poskey = { 5, 9 };
    SDL_Rect posletter = { 3, 7 };

    SDL_Rect *arraypos[4] = {NULL};
    size_t i;

    arraypos[0] = &poskey;
    arraypos[1] = &posletter;
    /* arraypos[2] & arraypos[3] are not used in this case */

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf (" arraypos[%zu]->x : %d\n", i, arraypos[i]->x);
        printf (" arraypos[%zu]->y : %d\n", i, arraypos[i]->y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/arraypos2
 arraypos[0]->x : 5
 arraypos[0]->y : 9
 arraypos[1]->x : 3
 arraypos[1]->y : 7
```

**Example with Array of Integers**

On the other hand, you are assigning `int` values to each element of `arraypos`, so it appears you want an array of integers, e.g.:

```
int arraypos[4] = {0};   /* always initialize your variables */
```

You have then declared `arraypos` as an *array of type `int` `4`. You can then assign integer values to each of the *index* positions `0-3` (remember -- all arrays are `zero` *indexed* in C). A short example of this (without SDL_Rect, but using a generic struct) would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} SDL_Rect;

int main (void) {

    SDL_Rect poskey = { 5, 9 };
    SDL_Rect posletter = { 3, 7 };
    int arraypos[4] = {0};
    size_t i;

    arraypos[0] = poskey.x;
    arraypos[1] = poskey.y;
    arraypos[2] = posletter.x;
    arraypos[3] = posletter.y;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof arraypos/sizeof *arraypos; i++)
        printf (" arraypos[%zu] : %d\n", i, arraypos[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/arraypos
 arraypos[0] : 5
 arraypos[1] : 9
 arraypos[2] : 3
 arraypos[3] : 7
```

Think about which situation you are attempting to impliment and then let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Several things look wrong.

First, the type of the array of pointers. You declared

```
 SDL_Rect *arraypos[4]; // wrong type
```

So you promise that each element of the array is a pointer to `SDL_Rect`. But apparently you want pointers to `int`, because the elements would contain pointers to `int` variables, that is `int*`. To declare generic pointers, use `void*`. So you want

```
 int* arraypos[4];
```

and later to set some element:

```
 arraypos[1] = &poskey.y;
```

Remember that the first element of an array has index `0` in C !

Then, to print some address, use `%p`  and cast that address to `(void*)`, so

```
printf("second pointer is %p\n", (void*)arraypos[1]);
```

You should not use `%d`, since on Linux/x86_64 `int` have 4 bytes and pointers have 8 bytes.

`void*` can be thought as the common supertype of every pointer type. So it is not exactly meaning pointer to `void`, but pointer to anything or any kind of pointer.

I strongly recommend you to spend several hours reading a good C programming book; the notion of pointer is tricky and essential. In particular, you'll need to understand what [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) means. Read also about [virtual address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (since pointers are addresses in such spaces, for most implementations of C on a desktop, laptop, or server operating system).

Of course, to dereference a pointer, use the `*` unary prefix [dereference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) of C, e.g.

```
printf("second pointer contains %d\n", *arraypos[1]);
```

If you find that notation confusing, use parenthesis, e.g. `*(arraypos[1])` but don't think of the dereference operator as giving the value of some variable (but the value in some memory location). To change the value of the referenced memory location, use the dereference operator on the left side of an assignment, e.g. `*(arraypos[1]) = 3;`; of course you can also assign pointers, so `arraypos[2] = arraypos[1];` is making a pointer alias.

Pointers are memory locations (or [memory addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address)), which is not the same as a [variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29) (for example, in a recursive function, each [call frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of that recursive function has locations for the local variables). A pointer can point to some dynamically allocated heap memory zone. Read about [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management), [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (at least for the terminology and concepts of GC).

Be scared of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) & [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and improve your code till you get no warnings at all. Then use the debugger (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available. Run your program `step` by step in the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and `p`rint the various variables of your program there.

Comment: thank you, but how could i extract the variable value from the adress stored in array element pointer ?

Comment: A pointer is a memory location, which is not the same as a variable.

Comment: yes they are not the same, but I guess there is a way to do so . Am i wrong ?

Comment: Can you help me get this right please ,, i really appreciate your effort

Comment: I did help you in my answer. We don't know the type of `poskey`

Comment: to get the variable value from a pointer we do use : int var = 1; *pointer = &var;   printf("%d \n",*pointer); so the result will be "1" . is that right ?

Comment: it's an SDL-Rect please see :  https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Rect   posletter and poskey are SDL_Rect

Comment: Yes, but the important thing to know is that pointers hold memory locations, not variables.

Comment: The type of `posletter`  should go into your question, not in comments

Comment: i'm sorry about that, i'm still new here  :)

Comment: It is still time to edit your question to improve it

Comment: Done editing :) thank you ,, still can't figure out where's the problem

Comment: Did you try to run your program in `gdb` after having improved your source program to avoid warnings from the compiler? You really should... We won't debug your bugs.

Comment: i will look for it thanks

Answer (score 0):

to start, this line: SDL_Rect *arraypos[4]; is defining an array of 4 pointers to instances of the struct SDL_Rect,

not 4 instances of an '*int'

Suggest:

```
int *arraypos[4];

// the rest of the 'setting the pointers' code is unchanged

// the rest of the printf() code is unchanged
```